# One Way Bindings not working when setting the object to a new instance

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have an object called Tel, which is bound to three controls as following.

```
  this.txtTelName.DataBindings.Add("Text", tel, "T_Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  this.chkActive.DataBindings.Add("Checked", tel, "T_Active", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
  this.txtNotes.DataBindings.Add("Text", tel, "T_Notes", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

This prompt all the values that the object has into the controls successfully.

I need to implement a **Next** button, which allow the users to save the values on the controls by saving the tel object and then create tel object with a new instance and cleaning all the controls. So the users can add a new record.

This is the next button code:

```
   private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     BllTel.Save(tel); //Saves the Tel entity 

     this.tel = new Model.DatabaseModels.Tel();
     tel.T_Active = BusinessLogic.Enums.StatusCodes.Active;

     txtTelName.Text = "";
     txtNotes.Text = "";
   }
```

Until here everything is OK, but after the user goes for the second time to add, the tel object does not bind the values they write in the controls, having the **T_Name** and **T_Notes** as nulls.

Notes: I've noticed as soon as the btnNext_Click method code block ends (on dubuggin), it goes through all the entities in the database (i see it, when debugging through, it passes through all the properties defined in the EDMX designer, and i can see it fetches all the values avaliable in the table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It of course works that way. When you change the instance of `tel`, it's no longer bound to your other controls. So you should define some method to bind data between them and **re-call** this method:

```
public void BindData(object tel){
   if(txtTelName.DataBindings["Text"] != null) 
      txtTelName.DataBindings.Remove(txtTelName.DataBindings["Text"]);
   txtTelName.Add("Text", tel, "T_Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
   if(chkActive.DataBindings["Checked"] != null)
      chkActive.DataBindings.Remove(chkActive.DataBindings["Checked"]);       
   chkActive.DataBindings.Add("Checked", tel, "T_Active", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);       
   if(txtNotes.DataBindings["Text"] != null)
     txtNotes.DataBindings.Remove(txtNotes.DataBindings["Text"]);       
   txtNotes.DataBindings.Add("Text", tel, "T_Notes", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
//then use it like this:
tel = new Model.DatabaseModels.Tel();
tel.T_Active = BusinessLogic.Enums.StatusCodes.Active;
BindData(tel);
```

Comment: Same results, the controls keeps the binding even though i create a new instance of the object. Maybe my question is not clear enough :(.

Comment: It looks that the bindings are set to a specific object instance. I change a little bit of your code and everything works perfect, Thanks
The binding needs to be cleared and recreated:
if (txtTelName.DataBindings["Text"] != null)
      {
        this.txtTelName.DataBindings.Clear();
        this.txtTelName.DataBindings.Add("Text", telData, "T_Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
      }

Comment: @Djavier89 don't use `DataBindings.Clear()`, it will remove all other Bindings if you have, just use `DataBindings.Remove`, if you don't know how, see my update.